# Windows Vista: Prevent mouse cursor blink on print screen or screen capture

Tags: windows-vista, screen-capture, mouse-cursor

I have a program that makes a repeated screen capture, but it makes my cursor blink. This is annoying. Can it be prevented?

Comment: What is the program?

Comment: Something I wrote in Java. There is another program TightVNC which does the same thing unless you turn off "Grab Transparent Windows". Unfortunately there are little to no customizations available in Java which is the only suitable language I know. If you would like to recreate this blink, you can just press the print screen button on your keyboard.